# Calculating results pro rata over several months with PowerQuery

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am currently stuck on below issue:

I have two tables that I have to work with, one contains financial information for vessels and the other contains arrival and departure time for vessels. I get my data combining multiple excel sheets from different folders:

[financialTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekpWm.png)

[voyageTimeTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKucX.png)

I have to calculate the result for above voyage, and apportion the result over June, July and August for both estimated and updated.

Time in June  : 4 hours (20/06/2020 20:00 - 23:59) + 10 days (21/06/2020 00:00 - 30/06/2020 23:59) = 10.1666

Time in July  : 31 full days

Time in August: 1 day + 14 hours (02/08/2020 00:00 - 14:00) = 1.5833

Total voyage duration = 10.1666 + 31 + 1.5833 = **42.7499**

The result for the "updated" financialItem would be the following:

Result June     : 100*(10.1666/42.7499) = 23.7816

Result July      : 100*(31/42.7499)     = 72.5148

Result August : 100*(1.5833/42.7499)    = 3.7036

sum  = 100

and then for "estimated" it would be twice of everything above.

This is the format I ideally would like to get:

[prorataResultTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLHGn.png)

I have to do this for multiple vessels, with multiple timespans and several voyage numbers.
Eagerly awaiting responses, if any. Many thanks in advance.

Brds,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but code below gives me your expected output:

```
let
    financialTable = Table.FromRows({{"A", 1, "profit/loss", 200, 100}}, type table [vesselName = text, vesselNumber = Int64.Type, financialItem = text, estimated = number, updated = number]),
    voyageTimeTable = Table.FromRows({{"A", 1, #datetime(2020, 6, 20, 20, 0, 0), #datetime(2020, 8, 2, 14, 0, 0)}}, type table [vesselName = text, vesselNumber = Int64.Type, voyageStartDatetime = datetime, voyageEndDatetime = datetime]),
    joined = 
        let
            joined = Table.NestedJoin(financialTable, {"vesselName", "vesselNumber"}, voyageTimeTable, {"vesselName", "vesselNumber"}, "$toExpand", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
            expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joined, "$toExpand", {"voyageStartDatetime", "voyageEndDatetime"})
        in expanded,
    toExpand = Table.AddColumn(joined, "$toExpand", (currentRow as record) =>
        let
            voyageInclusiveStart = DateTime.From(currentRow[voyageStartDatetime]),
            voyageExclusiveEnd = DateTime.From(currentRow[voyageEndDatetime]),
            voyageDurationInDays = Duration.TotalDays(voyageExclusiveEnd - voyageInclusiveStart),
            createRecordForPeriod = (someInclusiveStart as datetime) => [
                inclusiveStart = someInclusiveStart,
                exclusiveEnd = List.Min({
                    DateTime.From(Date.EndOfMonth(DateTime.Date(someInclusiveStart)) + #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),
                    voyageExclusiveEnd
                }),
                durationInDays = Duration.TotalDays(exclusiveEnd - inclusiveStart),
                prorataDuration = durationInDays / voyageDurationInDays,
                estimated = prorataDuration * currentRow[estimated],
                updated = prorataDuration * currentRow[updated],
                month = Date.MonthName(DateTime.Date(inclusiveStart)),
                year = Date.Year(inclusiveStart)
            ],
            monthlyRecords = List.Generate(
                () => createRecordForPeriod(voyageInclusiveStart),
                each [inclusiveStart] < voyageExclusiveEnd,
                each createRecordForPeriod([exclusiveEnd])
            ),
            toTable = Table.FromRecords(monthlyRecords)
        in toTable
    ),
    expanded = 
        let
            dropped = Table.RemoveColumns(toExpand, {"estimated", "updated", "voyageStartDatetime", "voyageEndDatetime"}),
            expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(dropped, "$toExpand", {"month", "year", "estimated", "updated"})
        in expanded
in
    expanded
```

The code tries to:

- join `financialTable` and `voyageTimeTable`, so that for each `vesselName` and `vesselNumber` combination, we know: `estimated`, `updated`, `voyageStartDatetime` and `voyageEndDatetime`.
- generate a list of months for the period between `voyageStartDatetime` and `voyageEndDatetime` (which get expanded into new table rows)
- for each month (in the list), do all the arithmetic you mention in your question
- get rid of some columns (like the old `estimated` and `updated` columns)

---

I recommend testing it with different `vesselName`s and `vesselNumber`s from your dataset, just to see if the output is always correct (I think it should be).

You should be able to manually inspect the cells in the `$toExpand` column (of the `toExpand` step/expression) to see the nested rows before they get expanded.